# Function property goes in global variables for no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery, latest version.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function ViewModel(){
        this.Impossible = "impossible!";
    }
    let vm = ViewModel();
});

$(window).on("beforeunload", function (e) {
    console.log("this: " + this.Impossible);
    console.log("window: " + window.Impossible);
    // return "Test";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5wkdxvhq/1/

How is it possible that "impossible!" gets logged? `Impossible` is wrapped by at least 2 functions, it definitely shouldn't be a global variable, yet there it is.

Is this a behavior of JQuery or JavaScript?

Is this standard behavior that I can rely on? Or is it some quirk that won't work in other browsers/future Knockout updates or a bad design practice by me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: You probably want `let vm = new ViewModel();` instead.

Comment: When you call the function without `new` you get the global context. This is a pretty good argument for using the class syntax (your code would have thrown).

Comment: This is why you should use arrow functions if you want a function to both be standalone, and have sane scoping/closure rules. If you had used an arrow function, "this" would be whatever it was outside of the function.

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvotes. It's a valid question, and a reasonable person would expect Javascript to work the way that it doesn't. It's not a bad question just because you're a Javascript expert and you've internalized the parts of it that are backward, deprecated scoping rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Impossible` isn't wrapped up by your functions declarative/lexical environments. It isn't local to your innermost function. If it was declared like this:

```
let Impossible = "impossible!"
//or
//var Impossible = "impossible!"
```

Then `Impossible` would have been local to that function and there wouldn't be any way to access it unless you use a closure.

What this does:

```
this.Impossible = "impossible!"
```

Is create a property definition on the `this` object. The value of `this` of course will change depending on the invocation of the surrounding function (`ViewModel`). In this case, you have called `ViewModel()` which means there's no object context and on scripts (non-strict mode) it will default to the global object (`window`).

Had you call it like this: `new ViewModel()` it would have created a new object and that would have been your `this` object which would have been assigned to your `vm` variable (and only accessible through it).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `$(document).ready(function (){})` apply global scope to the callback function `function (){}`. Try this, you will see `console.log(this)` is a Window object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(this);// this is window (global) object
});
```

Secondly, `this` is different when calling function and creating an object instance of a function, i.e `let vm = ViewModel();` vs `let vm = new ViewModel();`.

```js
function f1 () {
  function f2 () {
    console.log(this === window);
  }
  f2()
}
f1()
```

In your case, by creating instance of `ViewModel`, you will see the different values of `window.Impossible`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function ViewModel(){
        this.Impossible = "impossible!";
    }
    let vm = new ViewModel(); /// create instance instead of calling 
    console.log('vm:' + vm.Impossible);
    console.log("this: " + this.Impossible);
    console.log("window: " + window.Impossible);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```